# How to detect environment in CLI?

Tags: php

I have a different config files for a script that runs both on a dev and production server.
The question is, can I detect somehow which is which ?

Comment: You'd go more relevant answers if the question could bring some details (what did you tried so far, type of the config files, limitations of your CLI etc.)

Comment: Well, I would need a good solution for a reseller account where you only have .htaccess and php.ini at your disposal. Why I need is a good practice to make the difference between the two environment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a different bootstrap file to include depending on the server you're on. So

```
include "bootstrap.php";
// your script etc..
```

On the production box, bootstrap.php will have a constant `IS_DEV = FALSE`
On the development box, bootstrap.php will have the same constant `IS_DEV = TRUE`

So the same script will include the same file name, bootstrap.php, but the contents of bootstrap will have different values for the `IS_DEV` constant variable.

Comment: `$_SERVER` variables are not available when the script is run in CLI, so this won't work.

Comment: @takeshin k, then I removed that answer. Using a bootstrap file will also be effective.

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions to choose from:

- use `config.ini` and `config.ini.dist` strategy (`.dist` read when the other is not present)
- set some environment variable in `.htaccess` or virtual host config and read it using `getenv`
- check for existence of some file which does not exist on the other machine
- compare the current script path
- determine server IP

Basically, you just need to compare anything that differs on those two machines, or set some variable as a reference.

#### Edit after comment to the question:

Example with `.htaccess`:

In `.htaccess` (only on the staging server):

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT staging
```

In your PHP script:

```
if ('staging' === getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT')) {
    // use config_staging.ini
} else {
   // use config_develop.ini
}
```

Note you may have everything in one config file, just divide it to sections.

I think this may be called a good practice, as it is recommended in Zend Framework manual.

---

If you have access to the console (you have for sure in the development environment), you may set this flag via shell variable:

```
export APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=development
```

on Windows:

```
SET APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=development
```

and then read it using `getenv` from PHP.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: even If i have access to the .htaccess file the problem I'm looking to solve is for a script running in CLI. So using .htaccess to solve this the usual way won't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
  echo 'running in console!';
}
```

Comment: This distinguishes between the different SAPIs, but not where there are running.